# How to Fix 2004 Chevy Tahoe Heat Only Works if You Slowly Ratchet It Up

Tags: chevrolet, heater, tahoe

My Tahoe in general, the heat isn't working at all, only blowing cold air.

However, my son realized this morning that if he slowly moved the heat up in increments until he was finally able to get it to 90 degrees on the readout (which is usually very difficult to do) that it would finally blow some warm air out.

Was wondering what the problem might be and how I might fix it.

Comment: Is the question then, how should you go about fixing this? Possibly what the problem is which is causing this? Does it have the manual single zone, manual dual zone, or automatic dual zone (excluding rear heat) type of console in it?

Comment: It has the automatic dual zone in it.  Yes, I am wondering how I can fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: So what happens if you leave it on 90? Do the blend door actuators move without restriction? Does the HVAC controller set any codes? If you don't have an enhanced obd2 scantool it may be worth seeing if a shop will plug in a scanner and check for codes and check to see if the actuator calibration passes.